# Civievents - warning when user registers for event (CiviCRM 4.7.23)

Tags: civievent, drupal, sub-types

My CiviCRM version is: 4.7.23, Drupal: 7.56, PHP: 7.0
I have trouble with CiviEVENT. When participant fill and sendregistration form for event (when he doesnt exist in database) in CiviCRM i see this error:

> Notice: Undefined index: contact_sub_type w CRM_Contact_BAO_Contact::formatProfileContactParams() (linia 2010 z /home/sol/domains/staroflife.hekko24.pl/public_html/dev/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Contact.php).
>
> > Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given w CRM_Contact_BAO_Contact::formatProfileContactParams() (linia 2011 z /home/sol/domains/staroflife.hekko24.pl/public_html/dev/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Contact.php).
> >
> > > Notice: Undefined index: contact_sub_type w CRM_Contact_BAO_Contact::formatProfileContactParams() (linia 2013 z /home/sol/domains/staroflife.hekko24.pl/public_html/dev/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Contact.php).

CiviCRM did not show this error before updating CiviCRM. I will add that the participant registered to the event is automatically entered as a "Uczestnik (eng. participant)" contact subtype, configured as a contact.

The contact created in the database has a properly assigned contact type, but this annoying error appears.

You can reproduce the error trying to subscribe to the event at: dev.staroflife.hekko24.pl (developer and testing environment)
1. Select one of the events at the bottom of the page and click "register now"
2. Enter your data in the form
3. As a payment option select "płacę z dotpay"
4. In the payment test environment, select any method, accept, and click the payment solution as Accept.
5. When you return to CiviCRM you should see this error.

This same error i see in production version :(.

Answer (score 0):

You mention that you see this error on the production version as well.  This indicates that your production site is displaying errors, which is a PHP misconfiguration.  There are many [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332178/best-way-to-suppress-php-errors-on-production-servers) on Stack Overflow on setting PHP error reporting, but the best reference is the [error reporting page of the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php).

This doesn't solve the underlying issue, but it will hide the messages in production.

Comment: The problem occurs in the production version only in the drupal log.

Comment: Ah, OK!  I'd like to help you - I'm a former EMT (ambulance worker) and now I'm a CiviCRM developer.  In the question you say that any participant registered to the event is automatically entered as a contact subtype.  How do you do that?  Is that custom code?

Comment: Fantastic! Perfect fit for the activities of our foundation :)
(Sorry, my English is not very good, I use translator and correct his mistakes as far as I can :))

In the registration form, I used the additional fields assigned to the subtype "Uczestnik" only. Now that I've removed the specific fields for this subtype, the problem still occurs (the person added as a "contact" type).

I can create a user account for you if needed.